# Eclipse/ADT xml string to strings.xml automatically?

Tags: android, eclipse

If I have the following in a layout XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="string Test" />
```

it flags the 4th line "Hardcoded string should use @string resource"
Fine, I know that, and would like to.  Is there an option to select this line and have the IDE automatically add a `<string></string>` to the strings.xml and replace the `android:text=` to refer to that resource?

Comment: I think this is not possible because their is no any plugins of eclipse to do this..:(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an option to do this by selecting the text and have the IDE automatically do the job, just thank to JAL :

[How to add string resources in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106088/how-to-add-string-resources-in-eclipse)

By the way, in JAL's answer, when he says GO TO REFACTOR, he means REFACTOR in the menu bar, not right click's context menu.